# WiFi and Bluetooth is not found in raspberry pi 3 model b

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

[image]

i have raspberry pi 3 model b device in that installed raspbian OS. After installed the OS i check the blue-tooth and WiFi. while clicking the Bluetooth and WiFi it's shows Bluetooth adapter is not found and wireless interface is not found. how to solve this issue.

Comment: Is this a fresh unmodified installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be because of two things. one , the raspbian is corrupted download a new one and install again and check. two , the wifi and bluetooth module is fried. U can only use a wifi usb module or ethernet to connect in this case

Comment: yes i tried another OS also but i am facing same problem. And the raspberry pi 3 model b having inbuilt WiFi and blue-tooth.

Comment: @Vinod.s Yes, the raspberry pi 3 model b has inbuilt wifi. but after sometime in some boards the wifi is damaged and cannot be used again. The only thing u can do is change the board or use a wifi dongle if u dont want to spend some more money on buying a new board.

Answer (score 1):

On the Pi 3 you don't need a Bluetooth adapter as it is all ready built in, I suggest if the built in Bluetooth doesn't work you try reinstalling raspbian from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) and running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` in terminal.
If that still doesn't work get support from the supplier you purchased it from.

Comment: Already i done this apt-get update and upgrade. Still same issue

Comment: Get some support from the seller you bought it from.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue,I just reinstalled raspbian, the latest one "Stretch", and all is good now.
So install "[Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/)".

Comment: i tried stretch OS also but still facing same problem