# RPi won't detect built-in BT adapter

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth

My RPi 3 says no bluetooth adapter is detected and therefore won't let me connect to a device. The BT logo is greyed out instead of blue and running `sudo systemctl status bluetooth` it says the service is inactive (dead). I am also unable to start `hciuart.service`, which I believe is a part of it. Please help.

Comment: There's [some other](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=171999) people [who have](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75546/wifi-and-bluetooth-is-not-found-in-raspberry-pi-3-model-b) had the same issue - have you tried any of the fixes mentioned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi and Bluetooth is not found in raspberry pi 3 model b](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75546/wifi-and-bluetooth-is-not-found-in-raspberry-pi-3-model-b)

Comment: @JaromandaX I did--nothing worked. I might just give up and spend $35 on a new one...

Comment: so, you've even tried a brand new fresh install? cheaper than a new Pi  :p

Comment: @JaromandaX multiple times--I've even tried other OSes. I could prob use a model B+ anyway, but I might wait to see if they release the 4 on schedule in February.

Comment: You mention 'systemctl status bluetooth' returns inactive...but what else does it return?

Answer (score 3):

If you get no BT on a latest unmodified Raspbian image, and you're confident you flashed your SD card correctly, send your RPi back to the shop you got it from and get a new one.

Comment: It was waaaay past the warranty and I lost the box and had ordered off some Amazon seller a long time ago. Luckily the 3 B+ wasn't that expensive. I guess I just blew out the BT adapter with my garbage power supply thing I was using.